# Invert a TF frame axis

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to add a camera frame with x on the right, y up, and z **forward**. I am using the following command:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll map camera
```

First I tried to set up yaw, pitch, and roll manually by changing those three values. But there was always one axis that needed to be inverted which I could not do since if I change one of the three values, two axes change, not one. So, I ended up having a frame with x on the right, y up and z **backward**. Then I calculated a rotation matrix between those two coordinate frames. I found

```
     0 0 1
R = -1 0 0
     0 1 0
```

Then from the rotation matrix to yaw, pitch, and roll (-1.57, -0, 1.57). But the result is the same. How can I **flip only one axis** keeping the other two unchanged?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405119/invert-a-tf-frame-axis/) by [zrahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/109467/zrahman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-08-17**:
What do you mean by "x on the right"? After rotation you want the positive x-axis pointing to the left?

**Comment by [zrahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/109467/zrahman/) on 2022-08-17**:
@Mike Scheutzow The coordinate system I want should have x pointing to the right, y upward, and z forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124709/7248704)?

> - Check that the frame you get from your API is right-handed. You do so by computing the determinant of the 3x3 rotation part of your 4x4 transform matrix: it must be +1 or very close to it.
> - If it is -1, then flip one if its axis, i.e. change the sign of one of the columns of the 3x3 rotation.
> - Note carefully: I said "columns" because I assume that you apply a transform Q to a point x by multiplying as Q * x, x being a 4x1 column vector with the last component equal to one. If you use row vectors left-multiplied by Q you need flip a row.
> - If that determinant is +1, you have a bug someplace else.

You can try to use quaternions too, here are some great sources:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/208002/static-transformation-publisher/
- https://nu-msr.github.io/me495_site/lecture05_tf.html

P.S. This part from the second link seems to be related to your case

> ##Conventions

> From REP 105 Coordinate Frames for
> Mobile Platforms
>
> ```
> On a mobile robot, x is forward, y is left, and z is up 
>
> For cameras z is forward, x is right, y is down, and frame_id ends with _optical
> ```

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zrahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/109467/zrahman/) on 2022-08-17**:
@Ijaniec I checked those answers. It seems, ROS tf uses right-handed rules and there is no way I can get the frame I want. So, I will just multiply one axis by -1.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-18**:
OK, please report with the effects later! If this answer helped you, you can accept it as a correct one (right under the note, "✓") so it will be marked as solved in the queue